# .NET CLI: How is a local variable popped off the stack if not on top?

Tags: .net

I'm trying to figure out how Stack and Heap work.

So my question about Stack. For example, we have next code:

```
static void Main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Both variables will be pushed onto the stack, and variable 'b' will on top of variable 'a'.

If Stack has only Push and Pop operations, how variable 'a' can be read, without popping from stack 'b'?

Comment: I think you're mixing up the concept of stack memory and the Stack class in C#. They share some core concepts, but are two totally separate things.

Comment: It isn't popped - the stack containing local variables is treated more like an array inside the method., so individual variables can be accessed using an offset. (A simplification, but should give you the idea...)

Comment: I might point out that the actual location of variables, fields and objects is mostly irrelevant, **they may as well be on the moon for all the difference it makes to you**. The runtime does not have to conform to the standard x86/64 usage of the stack, it can use any other method that has the same result, including writing it down on paper

Comment: @charlieface I suspect using the moon for local storage may increase latency, since it is about 1.25 light-seconds away

Comment: @MarcGravell True, but that is an implementation detail :-) Obviously that particular example is a rather leaky abstraction, but the principle is the same: this has nothing to do with C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local variables are defined *before* the dynamic / flexible part of the stack, so what you actually have is (assuming no optimisations):

- define a & b in the stack-frame
- push 1 onto the dynamic stack (*after* a & b)
- write (pop) the value at the top of the stack into the location of a
- push 2 onto the dynamic stack
- write (pop) the value at the top of the stack into the location of b
- load (push) the value from the location of a onto the dynamic stack
- call Console.WriteLine

Local variable values can be accessed at any time; they are just relative offsets from the stack frame. The dynamic part of the stack used for transient values can only usually be accessed in strict order, but that isn't what contains the locations we're naming a and b.

Comment: You're now talking about the CLI execution stack? I guess that's not what the OP is talking about here.

Comment: @PMF I've read the question several times, and I stand by my interpretation of the question

Comment: @MarcGravell If OP is referring to C#, there is no concept of a stack at all, it's just memory locations. OP *must* be referring to the CLI

Comment: Thanks, I meant exactly stack in CLI. Sorry for the ambiguity

Answer (score 2):

You've got a misunderstanding here. Both a and b are put into the same stack frame, as they belong to the same method. Within `main` it is always known that a is at address Stackpointer + 8 and b at Stackpointer + 4 (for instance). For the execution stack, each method call is one stack frame (containing all local variables of a method). This is different from the `Stack` class, which contains one value per slot.